# Can't change UIFont size on UILabel [Swift]

Tags: swift, uilabel, uifont

I am trying to change the UIFont's size but when I enter a number it will not change it is still at size 17 and won't change even though I choose the number 70 or 100. Here is what I have tried:

```
labelTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold", size: 30)
```

And still gives me the result of a size 17

I figured out that using this line of code:

```
labelTitle.font.fontWithSize(30)
```

It worked changing the font size, but now the label changed the font to ".SFUIText-Regular"

I printed the results to the console to see the font and the size it has given me when It is not working:

```
print(labelTitle.font.fontName)
print(labelTitle.font.fontDescriptor())
```

The result in the console is this:

```
    **.SFUIText-Regular
UICTFontDescriptor <0x7c081580> = {
    NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute = CTFontRegularUsage;
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 17;
}**
```

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the font is correct?

Comment: Yes, It worked the font when the size didn't worked

Comment: Is it a system font or did you add it yourself?

Comment: When I just tried it, the font didn't exist, try unwrapping it to see if it actually exists ```labelTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold", size: 30)!```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 30)`

not `UIFont(name: "Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold", size: 30)`